# Attempted to load class "Stripe" from namespace "Stripe". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Tags: symfony, stripe-payments, symfony3.x

Impossible to load Stripe classe in my Symfony controller see :

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Stripe\Stripe;



class PointsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     *
     * @Route("/points/buy", name="points_buy")
     */
    public function buyAction(Request $request)
    {

        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_');



        return $this->render('points/buy.html.twig', [

        ]);
    }

}
```

Stripe added with composer in vendor directory

I tried Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_') but same error ...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you're importing Stripe\Stripe in your `use` statement then I don't think you need the fully qualified class name.

```
use Stripe\Stripe;

//// etc.

/**
 *
 * @Route("/points/buy", name="points_buy")
 */
public function buyAction(Request $request)
{
    Stripe::setApiKey($secretKey);
}
```

Here's a [Stripe service](https://github.com/oxenfree/duesbot/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Services/StripeManager.php) I created for one of my projects.

Comment: Okay. Now clear cache a couple times and make sure your cache and log directories are writeable. https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/setup/file_permissions.html

Comment: What should I check in the vendor foler?

Comment: That there's a Stripe directory. You brought it in with composer and there were no errors. Is the directory really there?